# Finding $\lim_{t\to\infty}y$ for the initial value problem $2\frac{dy}{dt}-y=4 \sin(3t)$ with $y(0)=y_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> I have the initial value problem
> $$2\frac{dy}{dt}-y=4 \sin(3t), \quad y(0)=y_0$$
> I have to determine $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} y$.

I found the solution of the homogeneous problem and then a particular solution, so I found that the solution is:

$$y(t) = \frac {1} {37} [(37 y_0 + 24) e^{t/2} - 4 \sin(3t) - 24 \cos(3t) ]$$

My problem is to determine the limit above.

By using Taylor expansion, I found that
$$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} y = (y_0+1) \infty$$
But I don't understand what happens for the case $y_0=-1.$ On the other hand, for $y_0=- \frac{24}{37}$, we have
$$y(t) = -\frac {1} {37} [ 4 \sin(3t) + 24 \cos(3t) ]$$

Any help please?

Comment: When $t\to\infty$ the sine and cosine don't have a limit, so the limit does not exist.

Comment: Thank you, can you just explain a bit more the case =0 about sine and cosine